# Joint distribution R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a list of 10 stocks, with each having a time series of log returns (AIG, JPM,...). I have calculated the log returns for each of the stocks as follows:

```
PB29 <- as.numeric(unlist(AIG[2]))
n31 <- length(PB29)
R.AIG <- (log(PB29[-1]/PB29[-n31]))
```

So I have a list of 10 time series of log stock returns (R.AIG, R.JPM, R.PNC,...) and I would like to have their joint distribution. How can I do that in R?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I coincidentally just finished writing about examining joint distribution structure in finance applications just some minutes ago [here](http://prescientmuse.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/a-brief-introduction-to-copula.html).

The joint distribution depends on your assumptions. If you are looking for a non-parametric joint distribution, you may consider using the empirical distribution. The copula package, has the function C.n which will deliver on the goods.

```
#u are points at which you'd like the empirical distribution to be evaluated.
ec <- C.n(u, U=yourData)
```

If you're assuming a multivariate normal distribution then you can do something like:

```
cop <- normalCopula(c(0.6,0.36, 0.6),dim=3,dispstr="un")
u <- pobs(yourData)
fitted.cop <- fitCopula(cop, u, method="itau")
```

You can then use the copula to derive densities. Have a look at the [copula](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/copula/copula.pdf) package manual for more details.

You can also use the mvtnorm package (check out the manual). The variance matrix can be calculated with the usual cor command and passed in.

Comment: thanks very much, the Fact is i would like the joint distribution to be stable(normal tempered stable) or to have a Student t distribution.

Comment: Have a look at the mvtnorm package Alexandre. You can calculate the correlation matrix yourself and pass it in as the sigma argument. The manual has examples.